# Usb_cam ignoring camera_frame_id

Tags: ros, camera, stereo-camera, usb-cam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file for starting a stereo USB camera:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="device_left" default="/dev/video1" />
    <arg name="device_right" default="/dev/video2" />
    <arg name="width" default="320" />
    <arg name="height" default="240" />
    <arg name="format" default="yuyv" />
    <group ns="raw_stereo">
        <node name="left" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen">
            <param name="video_device" value="$(arg device_left)" />
            <param name="image_width" value="$(arg width)" />
            <param name="image_height" value="$(arg height)" />
            <param name="pixel_format" value="$(arg format)" />
            <param name="camera_frame_id" value="left_camera" />
            <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
            <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file://$(find stereo_slam_test)/config/usb1-config-left.yml" />
        </node>
        <node name="right" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen">
            <param name="video_device" value="$(arg device_right)" />
            <param name="image_width" value="$(arg width)" />
            <param name="image_height" value="$(arg height)" />
            <param name="pixel_format" value="$(arg format)" />
            <param name="camera_frame_id" value="right_camera" />
            <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
            <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file://$(find stereo_slam_test)/config/usb1-config-right.yml" />
        </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

However, when I run this, I get the warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1431313131.230893149]: [head_camera] does not match name left_camera in file ~/git/stereo_slam_test/src/stereo_slam_test/config/usb1-config-left.yml
[ INFO] [1431313131.230983626]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video1) at 320x240 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS
[ INFO] [1431313131.273715224]: camera calibration URL: ~/git/stereo_slam_test/src/stereo_slam_test/config/usb1-config-right.yml
[ WARN] [1431313131.275529366]: [head_camera] does not match name right_camera in file ~/git/stereo_slam_test/src/stereo_slam_test/config/usb1-config-right.yml
```

Why is it using the "head_camera" frame id for both cameras when I explicitly set it to "left_camera" and "right_camera" in my launch file?

Edit: The output of `rosparam get /raw_stereo`:

```
left:
  camera_frame_id: left_camera
  camera_info_url: file:///home/chris/git/stereo_slam_test/src/stereo_slam_test/config/usb1-config-left.yml
  image_height: 240
  image_raw:
    compressed: {format: jpeg, jpeg_quality: 80, png_level: 9}
    compressedDepth: {depth_max: 10.0, depth_quantization: 100.0, png_level: 9}
    theora: {keyframe_frequency: 64, optimize_for: 1, quality: 31, target_bitrate: 800000}
  image_width: 320
  io_method: mmap
  pixel_format: yuyv
  video_device: /dev/video1
right:
  camera_frame_id: right_camera
  camera_info_url: file:///home/chris/git/stereo_slam_test/src/stereo_slam_test/config/usb1-config-right.yml
  image_height: 240
  image_raw:
    compressed: {format: jpeg, jpeg_quality: 80, png_level: 9}
    compressedDepth: {depth_max: 10.0, depth_quantization: 100.0, png_level: 9}
    theora: {keyframe_frequency: 64, optimize_for: 1, quality: 31, target_bitrate: 800000}
  image_width: 320
  io_method: mmap
  pixel_format: yuyv
  video_device: /dev/video2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208935/usb_cam-ignoring-camera_frame_id/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From reading the usb_cam documentation and source code, your configuration looks correct. After running your launch file, you should be able to confirm that the desired parameters are being set correctly by running `rosparam get /raw_stereo`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-11**:
I am. But where is this "head_camera" name coming from and why does it complain if I use a different name than that? Is that hard-coded in usb_cam?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-11**:
head_camera appears to be the default camera frame name in the usb_cam node.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-11**:
But then why doesn't camera_frame_id override it?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-11**:
I don't know. As suggested in my answer, please run `rosparam get /raw_stereo` and include the output in your question.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-11**:
Sorry, I've appended the output. It seems the camera_frame_id is being set, even though it does not match the camera name in the yml files.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-11**:
There appears to be an undocumented camera_name parameter; try setting that to the name of your camera. See: https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam/blob/bce395a9a543f89830668977b227ddf77c84fc17/nodes/usb_cam_node.cpp#L96

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thank you! That was it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-11**:
Ok. I've updated the documentation on the wiki page.